# CMIS:document query error

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, cmis

**I need all documents under specific folder path**

My Query is :

```
query = "SELECT cmis:name FROM cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:Company  Home/st:Sites/*\"')"
```

The following exception occurs:

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: 05070198 Request failed 400 /solr4/alfresco/cmis?wt=json&amp;fl=DBID%2Cscore&amp;rows=100&amp;df=TEXT&amp;start=0&amp;loc
le=en_IN&amp;alternativeDic=DEFAULT_DICTIONARY&amp;cmisVersion=CMIS_1_1&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&amp;fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON
at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:487)
```

Path of my document is like:

```
/Sites/site_name/documentLibrary/PIM Data/3600011/rnd/VphotometricDrawings.polar diagram/en
```

Comment: I'm not sure your PATH part of the query looks right, you might wanna look into that, for example "SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/*\"')".

Comment: Thanks Lista,
This is working fine SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/*\"')"

But I want to fetch from folder like "PIM Data"

 query = "SELECT cmis:name FROM cmis:document WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:site_name/cm:documentLibrary*\"')"

Comment: Thanks Lista 

It is working..

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll move the comment into an answer, so you can accept it next time around.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your PATH part of the query looks right, you might wanna look into that, for example:

> "SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE
>   CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/*\"')".

Also, see the following link:

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/references/API-JS-iso9075Encode.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. It should work

```
String folder_query = "SELECT cmis:path,cmis:objectId,cmis:allowedChildObjectTypeIds FROM cmis:folder where CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:mysite/cm:myLibrary/"
                + your own path + "//*\"')";
```

It will give you the folder ID. By using folder ID you can access your documents.

```
String query = "Select cmis:contentStreamMimeType,cmis:objectId FROM cmis:document where IN_FOLDER('" + objectId
                    + "') and cmis:contentStreamMimeType = 'application/pdf'";
```